# Generate tables and corresponding models using cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, model

My application allows users (admin) to design their own forms, and each form would have a corresponding table to store that information. So whenever the form is created, I would need to generate a table in the database, for that form, based on its input type and possible value.

Creation of table can be done using `$this->Model->query('create table ....')` method, but one thing I am unable to figure out is, how would I later generate a model for the corresponding table?

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain further?  You want to create tables dynamically and generate the appropriate models dynamically?  Or are you just looking to bake models for existing tables?

Comment: I would like to dynamically create tables and then generate appropriate models, if that is possible. How can I create tables dynamically though using cakePHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not create a self-modifying application. This will soon become a headache, if only from an optimization standpoint. Even worse than modifying a database dynamically is to generate models dynamically. Don't do it.

If your goal is to create an application that allows users to create forms, you will have to create a meta-application that stores information about forms and schemas *as data* in a database.

```
id | form_id | field_name | field_type | length | ...
---+---------+------------+------------+--------+----
1  | 42      | firstname  | string     | 255    | ...
2  | 42      | lastname   | string     | 255    | ...
...
```

Based on these meta information you need to dynamically create the actual forms and store the input data in a similar meta-fashion in your database.

Unless you're trying to make a phpMyAdmin *database administration* clone, this is the only realistic way. *If* you're trying to make a *database administration* app, you won't create models dynamically, but just use one *database manipulation model*, which would do pretty much everything via `$this->query()`.

Either way, you're creating a meta application, which is often a bad idea. You're trying to give the job of programmers (designing and creating databases and forms) to users, which will inevitably do a worse job. That's of course just my humble opinion, I don't know your business case.

Comment: how would this->query work?? don't we need a specific model to run the query method?

Comment: @macha You just need *one* model, *any* model, a `DatabaseManipulationModel` or something along these lines. `query()` lets you run **raw SQL queries**, for *any* table or database, so you don't need a specific model for every table.

Comment: I would agree with your meta data solution, which is similar to what drupal's database is used to store nodes of content, but the forms that have to be created would by an admin, so I am made to believe that the admin would be careful enough while creating new forms.

Answer (score 0):

How about using **$this->Model->query** to create the table, then use **Bake** to create the views/models/controllers? Giving that you'll only need basic CRUD. But I do agree that this will become un-mantainable soon.